# Can't access UserControl's CodeBehind Class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following line of code that works with one user control and not the other:

```
Folder_UserControl1 myVar = (Folder_UserControl1)LoadControl(@"~/Folder/UserControl1.ascx");
```

but it does not work with this: Folder_UserControl22

I get the following compile error:

```
Error   4   The type or namespace name 'Folder_UserControl22' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I checked everything the files look identical, both are public partial classes.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you registered the user control (Folder_UserControl22) at the top of the asp.net page?

Comment: No problem, I might as well post my solution as an answer so that you can accept.

Comment: Yes, this way I can close the questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this error many times and it is usually down to the fact that I've duplicated custom components and haven't been bothered to register the new control at the top of the aspx page. So this is what you should do...

Generic registration syntax:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Custom" Namespace="CustomControlNamespace" Assembly= "CustomControl" %>
```

And the MS documentation

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321749

And of course, that means you can include the custom controls from then on in the main code like so:

```
<Custom:CustomControl id="CustomControl1" parameter1="value1" parameter2="value2" runat="server"/>
```